# how to tag a variable as global in an indirect way

Tags: python, global, local

I recently learned that one can use `global()` dictionary to directly define global variables. However, when the variable defined in such a manner needs to be updated, I must tag the global variable definition with the `global` keyword. Hence, just putting the variable in the global dictionary is not enough. Here is a simple code to demonstrate my point.

```
def foo():
   globals()['var'] = 3 
   global var #without this code won't even run because var is assumed to be local
   var += 4
   print(var)

foo()
print(var)
```

My question is: Is there a way to implicitly notify the interpreter that var is actually a global variable, i.e. without using `global var`. If python had a macro like C, this would have been easy to do.

Comment: No.  A variable that is modified in a function is local unless it is explicitly declared otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

The `global` statement is the only way to associate a local variable to a global one, so you can't eliminate it.  But if you're going to use it anyway, there's no need to use the `globals()` dictionary to create it, and your code can simplify a bit:

```
def foo():
    global var
    var = 3
    var += 4
    print(var)

>>> var
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#993>", line 1, in <module>
    var
NameError: name 'var' is not defined
>>> foo()
7
>>> var
7
```

Let me go on record that using globals like this is a bad idea.  It makes it much more difficult to track how your program state is being used and updated.